# Endless video chat?

Tags: video, streaming, webvideos

Looking to create a video conferencing experience between 2 offices. Want to make it like a window where people can just walk up to the camera/screen/mic and see who is there. Is there a cheap way to do this- to have a dedicated video line through the internet like this between 2 offices? Possibly free? I remember there being a google hangouts hack but want to avoid doing anything sketchy

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use a google video hangout, or a skype video chat or any number of other video chat solutions. Because you are only wanting the communication to be between two offices, you don't need any specialist video conferencing software.